# PHP: socket_recv() failed; reason: Success?

Tags: php, websocket

I am using PHP in socket server. I create socket and write socket but cannot read. I have attached all the client socket in ***clients*** array. I use flag ***MSG_DONTWAIT*** because if I use other flag I cannot handshake with other clients. Help me find bug here or give me code that will work in this context.

```
foreach($clients as $client) {
    if ( socket_recv($client, $buf, 1024, MSG_DONTWAIT) >= 1) {
        print_r($buff);
    }  else {
       echo "socket_recv() failed; reason: " .                                 
              socket_strerror(socket_last_error($socket)) . "\n";
    }         
}
```

However, I get message below. Kindly help me find out to receive message from client.

```
PHP: socket_recv() failed; reason: Success
```

Jquery Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //create a new WebSocket object.
    var wsUri = "ws://172.28.21.45:9000";   
    var websocket = false;

    websocket = new WebSocket(wsUri);

    $("#messageform").click( function(ev) {

        ev.preventDefault();

        var message = $("#message").val();
        var packet = {
            message: message
        };

        console.log(packet);
        websocket.send(JSON.stringify(packet));

        $("#message").val('');
    });

    websocket.onopen = function(ev) {

        //ev.preventDefault();
        $(".notification").html('<a href="messagearchive.php"><img src="images/bell.svg" width="25px;"/><br/><span style="color: green;">Connected</span>    ');
    }

    websocket.onmessage = function(ev) {

        ev.preventDefault();
    }
    websocket.onerror = function(ev)  {
        $(".notification").append('<p>Socket has error</p>');
    }
    websocket.onclose = function (ev) {
        $(".notification").append('<p>Socket is closed</p>');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The function socket-recv returns the **number of bytes read** or **false** in case of error ([this information is in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-recv.php#refsect1-function.socket-recv-returnvalues)).

On *disconnections* you receive 0 bytes, and your `if` isn't checking for this condition.

I suggest you to change your php reading code a little bit:

```
foreach($clients as $client) {
  $bytes = socket_recv($client, $buf, 1024, MSG_DONTWAIT);
  if ($bytes === false) {
    echo "socket_recv() failed; reason: " .                                 
          socket_strerror(socket_last_error($socket)) . "\n";
  } elseif ($bytes === 0) {
    echo "Disconnection\n";
  } else {
    print_r($buf); // typo, 6 char SO limit
  }
}
```

However, this does not explains why you are not able to read data.